# SP2 Upgrade Failure - Corrupt User Profile Database

Tags: user-profile-service, upgrade, service-pack

I'm trying to perform an upgrade to SP2 on Sharepoint 2010.  However during the final stages of the upgrade process, it fails.  Digging into the upgrade logs I see this error as the reason:

```
Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot find data type tvpProfileExportItems.
Must declare the table variable "@Items".
Parameter or variable '@Items' has an invalid data type.
```

I have no idea how to fix this and I can't delete / recreate the database as it had production data in it.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to get around this?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally sorted this issue.  I ended up ringing MS on it and their only official supported fix was to delete and recreate the User Profile Service Application & it's database.  However this was on our production server and I couldn't do that.  Luckily based on their information I was able to come up with an unofficial fix.

The error happens because somehow the user profile database is missing datatypes & stored procedures it should contain.  So my fix for this was to provision a new user profile service application with a new database, export the datatypes & stored procedures from it and import them into my existing database.  The upgrade then ran successfully.

**Step 0 - Backup your sharepoint server & database!!**

**Step 1 - Create a new user profile service application**

- Log on to central administration
- Go to Application Management > Manage service applications
- New > User Profile Service Application
- Set it up with a name "UPA Temp" and new databases, for this example I'll use "Profile DB Temp", "Social DB Temp" and "Sync DB Temp"
- Click create (Note: I had to go in and add my farm account as sysadmin for this to work - I got an error about the master db)

**Step 2 - Export the stored procedures & data types**

- Open SQL management studio on your sharepoint database server
- Log on to your sharepoint instance and find the newly created user profile database - "Profile DB Temp" in my example
- Verify it has the datatype 'tvpProfileExportItems' by expanding the database, Programmability > Types > User-Defined Table Types.  You should see 'dbo.tvpProfileExportItems'
- Verify it has the stored procedure 'profile_ADImportAddFailedItems' by expanding the database, Programmability > Stored Procedures.  You should see 'dbo.profile_ADImportAddFailedItems' in the list.
- Export the datatype by right-clicking the database, going to Tasks > Generate Scripts
- Under 'Choose Objects', select specific database objects and select 'User-Defined Table Types'.  Click Next and save the script as 'profile_datatypes.sql'
- Export the stored proceedures by right-clicking the database, going to Tasks > Generate Scripts
- Under 'Choose Objects', select specific database objects and select 'Stored Procedures'.  Click Next and save the script as 'profile_procedures.sql'

**Step 3 - Delete the temporary User Profile Service Application**

- We no longer need the temporary application we created in Step 1, so log into Central Administration
- Go to Application Management > Manage service applications
- Find the "UPA Temp" application you created in step 1, select it and delete it.  Check the box to delete data associated with this application.  **MAKE SURE YOU DELETE THE TEMPORARY ONE, NOT YOUR LIVE ONE!**

**Step 4 - Import the datatype & procedures into your existing User Profile database**

- Open SQL management studio on your sharepoint database server
- Log on to the sharepoint instance
- File > Open > File and open 'profile_datatypes.sql' you saved in Step 2
- At the top of the file it will say 'Use [Profile DB Temp]' or whatever you called your temporary database.  Change this to your live profile database
- Execute the script (F5).  It should complete successfully
- Close that file and then File > Open > File and open 'profile_procedures.sql' you saved in Step 2
- At the top of the file it will say 'Use [Profile DB Temp]' or whatever you called your temporary database.  Change this to your live profile database
- Execute the script (F5).  You will get a bunch of warnings about procedures already existing.  This is fine, it'll create any that were missing.

**Step 5 - Run the update again**

- That should be it - your User Profile Service Application now has the datatypes & stored procedures it was missing and any cumulative updates should complete successfully!

Best of luck anyone that attempts this!